# How can i set the view Controller within the screen area with tabbar controller

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, ios9

I have created the tabbar controller programmatically. Below is my code of Tab bar controller.

```
RecordedAudioListViewController *recordedAudioListViewController = [[RecordedAudioListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RecordedAudioListViewController" bundle:nil];

recordedAudioListViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Recording" image:spongebob tag:0];
 UINavigationController *firstNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:recordedAudioListViewController];
    firstNavController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    RecordViewController *recordViewController = [[RecordViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RecordViewController" bundle:nil];

    recordViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Record" image:patrick tag:1];
    UINavigationController *secondNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:recordViewController];
    secondNavController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    SettingViewController *settingViewController = [[SettingViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SettingViewController" bundle:nil];
    settingViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Setting" image:spongebob tag:2];
    UINavigationController *thirdNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:settingViewController];
    thirdNavController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstNavController, secondNavController, thirdNavController, nil];
    tabBarController.delegate = self;
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;

    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In Below image, you can see view controller goes out of screen on top side.

[image]

Comment: i see that you are running the iphone app on ipad. This should be corrected using autolayout

Comment: Is it possible with Tabbar, as you see in above code. Tabbar added programmatically. How can i apply auto layout option ?